# How to set multiple env home variables on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, environment-variables, homebrew

I am trying to set JAVA_HOME, GRADLE_HOME and GRAILS_HOME variables on my Mac OS. After googling around I created a file .bash_profile in my home directory and set the following values in it.

.**bash_profile**

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export GRADLE_HOME=$(/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/4.4)
export GRAILS_HOME=$(/usr/local/Cellar/grails/3.3.2)
```

I also went on the command prompt and then executed the following command

$ **source .bash_profile**

```
-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/4.4: is a directory
-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/grails/3.3.2: is a directory
```

Killed and then restarted the terminal.

**echo $JAVA_HOME**

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home
```

**echo $GRADLE_HOME**

**echo $GRAILS_HOME**

Both the above commands gives me nothing, whereas just the first command works.

Moreover how can I find out where my grails and gradle installation happened. I installed both of them threw `brew` cli.

I also notice that all the above 3 programs are working fine when invoked through command prompt.

**$ java -version**

```
java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)
```

**$ gradle -v**

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-12-06 09:05:06 UTC
Revision:     cf7821a6f79f8e2a598df21780e3ff7ce8db2b82

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_152 (Oracle Corporation 25.152-b16)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.2 x86_64
```

**$ grails -v**

```
| Grails Version: 3.3.2
| Groovy Version: 2.4.13
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_152
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using a variable instead of a string.

Try

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/4.4
export GRAILS_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/grails/3.3.2
```

Instead of using `$(...)`